# Cannot get imgur v3 api request to authorize using curl or other bash utility

Tags: bash, authentication, curl, imgur

I'm trying to scrape some public data from imgur.com using the [v3 imgur api](http://api.imgur.com/) but whenever I make a request using curl I'm getting a 401.

This is how I'm calling the API ([using this example from the example python app](https://github.com/jacobgreenleaf/imgur-python/blob/master/Imgur/Auth/Anonymous.py)) -

```
curl -F "Authorization=Client-ID <my_client_id_provided_by_registering_my_app>" https://api.imgur.com/3/gallery/hot/viral/0.json
```

I've also tried

```
curl -F "client_id=<my_client_id>" https://api.imgur.com/3/gallery/hot/viral/0.json
```

So my question is, **what format is the imgur api expecting for the auth header and how can I leverage it using curl or some other common bash utility?**

Comment: You may want to change your actual client ID because it's been exposed in the second code sample of your question. You could delete the question and continue using the same ID but that would be a lot less safe.

Comment: I pulled it out - thanks for pointing that out.  I'll look into getting it changed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The switch `-F` (or `--form`) is for sending HTTP forms. What you should use instead is `-H` (`--header`):

```
curl --header "Authorization: Client-ID $YOUR_ID" https://api.imgur.com/3/gallery/hot/viral/0.json
```

Comment: Good suggestion but it doesn't seem to be working.  I've got something working using python and urllib2 to set the header so I'm fairly certain I'm going about this the right way.

Comment: How does it fail? Post the output `curl` gives you with the `-v` switch: `curl -v --header [...]`.

Comment: Actually - that did work.  I had to change the formatting I had in the header from "Authorization=" to "Authorization: ", like it is in your answer.  Thanks for the help!